# Radioactivity safety measures

Tags: radioactivity

I am making a machine at home . The machine uses sensors , magnets, Arduino and circuits. So do I need to take any precautions while handling these equipments? Are any of these a potential source of radioactive radiation?

Comment: It is pretty hard to unknowingly end up with enough radioactive material to be harmful. But do be careful of bananas (https://xkcd.com/radiation/).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the sensors and what you're building. The only sensor that I know is radioactive is a smoke detector (ionization). The smoke detector has a radioactive material inside (a very, very small amount) called Americium<sup>241</sup> (Am<sup>241</sup>). It emits very small amounts of Alpha rays, which is essentially helium<sup>4</sup> without electrons. They can be stopped by a piece of paper. Am<sup>241</sup> also emits low-power gamma rays, which, while they are very hard to stop and dangerous, you shouldn't be too concerned, because the smoke detector blocks all of that stuff. If you want to be really safe, though, stay about 6-8 feet from it. Other than that, I doubt that there's anything radioactive in there, but you should probably edit your post stating what sensors you're using.